# MariaDB Memory_used keep increasing

Tags: mysql, memory, mariadb

I recently restarted my MariaDB (Mysql) server after updating to the last version (Mariadb 10.1.9). But since then, my nagios report a constant memory used increase and I can't figure out where it comes from.

The memory used was already recorded by Nagios as 150.000 and currently it increase constantly. The request of this morning show 620.000 :

QUERY WARNING: 'SELECT ROUND(VARIABLE_VALUE/1024/1024) FROM information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = "Memory_used"' returned 620.000000

Is it possible that the problem come from the update + restart, or a different configuration file since package update or simply something else?

Thanks for your help

UPDATE

```
show variables like "%cache%"
Variable_name
Value
aria_pagecache_age_threshold
300
aria_pagecache_buffer_size
134217728
aria_pagecache_division_limit
100
aria_pagecache_file_hash_size
512
binlog_cache_size
32768
binlog_stmt_cache_size
32768
have_query_cache
YES
host_cache_size
279
innodb_disable_sort_file_cache
OFF
innodb_ft_cache_size
8000000
innodb_ft_result_cache_limit
2000000000
innodb_ft_total_cache_size
640000000
join_cache_level
2
key_cache_age_threshold
300
key_cache_block_size
1024
key_cache_division_limit
100
key_cache_file_hash_size
512
key_cache_segments
0
max_binlog_cache_size
18446744073709547520
max_binlog_stmt_cache_size
18446744073709547520
metadata_locks_cache_size
1024
query_cache_limit
1048576
query_cache_min_res_unit
4096
query_cache_size
1048576
query_cache_strip_comments
OFF
query_cache_type
OFF
query_cache_wlock_invalidate
OFF
stored_program_cache
256
table_definition_cache
400
table_open_cache
64
thread_cache_size
16


show variables like "%buffer%"
Variable_name
Value
aria_pagecache_buffer_size
134217728
aria_sort_buffer_size
268434432
bulk_insert_buffer_size
8388608
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown
OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now
OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_filename
ib_buffer_pool
innodb_buffer_pool_instances
8
innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort
OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup
OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_now
OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_populate
OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_size
134217728
innodb_change_buffer_max_size
25
innodb_change_buffering
all
innodb_log_buffer_size
16777216
innodb_sort_buffer_size
1048576
join_buffer_size
262144
join_buffer_space_limit
2097152
key_buffer_size
16777216
mrr_buffer_size
262144
myisam_sort_buffer_size
8388608
net_buffer_length
8192
preload_buffer_size
32768
read_buffer_size
262144
read_rnd_buffer_size
524288
sort_buffer_size
524288
sql_buffer_result
OFF

show variables like "%max_connections%"
Variable_name
Value
extra_max_connections
1
max_connections
151
```

Comment: Could you also include the cache and buffer variables?  
You may also check the maximum configured memory usage of the MySQL with mysqltuner.

Comment: Were a lot of queries running overnight?  Does the OS (eg, "top") also say about 620M for mysqld?  About how much data (total) in all the tables?

Comment: @mihaly-vukovics Which variables exactly, from information_schema ? I had to restart my mysqld server because the value was becoming critical, maybe I need to wait until the memory used go up again to show you this variables.

Comment: @rick-james I have only few databases: Custom 11Mo, MediaWiki: 127Mo, Prestashop: 155Mo, Redmine: 20Mo = 313 Mo. Some queries are running on mediawiki by robot crawling but nothing crazy, as usual I would expect. I just restarted mysqld so I will check with "top" later.

Comment: `show variables like "%cache%";`

Comment: `show variables like "%buffer%";`

Comment: `show variables like "%max_connections%";`

Comment: @mihaly-vukovics I updated the first post with this variables. As I mentioned I restarted the mysqld service this morning.

Comment: How much RAM do you have?  620M is not a problem even if you have only 4GB.

Answer (score 0):

3 more parameters are missing for the exact calculation:

`tmp_table_size,
thread_stack,
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size`

But 620MB of memory consumption is normal for the configuration you provided.
I assume that the upgrade also modified the configuration files of MariaDB.

Comment: tmp_table_size: 16777216, thread_stack: 294912, innodb_additional_mem_pool_size: 8388608

Comment: The issue is that my nagios reported a Memory_used of 151.000 normally, and the value was 620MB when I posted here but this morning it was more than 1000MB and marked as critical by Nagios. That's why I restarted the server.

Comment: Total memory consumption of MariaDB should be around 600MB (when all 151 connections active!). The remaining 400MB is allocated by other OS and non-OS processes. Check the memory allocation of other processes with atop/top utlity.

Comment: I'm talking about the Memory_used of information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS that returned 1029.000000 this morning. I don't think it's related to other processus. Plus when I restart my mysql server this morning, the same variable go back to 151.000000 which before I updated the mysql server was the constant value of Memory_used.

Comment: Its clear, that the update changed something. What memory usage reported by the OS?

Comment: Currently as I restarted mysqld, the "Memory_used"' returned 170.00000 (increased slowly from 150 to 170 for the last 3 hours).

`sudo top return: GiB Mem :  3.7/23.592`

`sudo atop return: MEM | tot    23.6G | free    2.1G | cache  19.7G | buff  328.2M | slab  711.0M`

Comment: How much MariaDB memory consumpition repoted by atop and the memory_used currently.

Comment: `innodb_additional_mem_pool_size` is deprecated and soon to be removed; ignore it.

Comment: `tmp_table_size` is a messy one.  Tmp tables are _usually_ not used.  But at the other extreme, every connection could be using multiple ones.

Comment: `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Max_used_connections';` -- that will say how many of the 151 were actually used (high-water-mark).

Comment: SELECT ROUND(VARIABLE_VALUE/1024/1024) FROM information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = "Memory_used" : 445
sudo top : Global GiB Mem :  4.2/23.592
 2892 mysql     20   0  758.8m 226.8m   0.0  0.9   2:05.83 S  `- mysqld

Comment: Max_used_connections: 10

Comment: @MihalyVukovics : It becomes critical again 'SELECT ROUND(VARIABLE_VALUE/1024/1024) FROM information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = "Memory_used"' returned 696.000000.
The OS memory seems stable thought.

Comment: Could you please check virtual and residental memory usage of the mysql process?

Comment: @MihalyVukovics Today
VIRT  783.7m 
RES 232.5m
2 days ago (see comment above)
VIRT  758.8m
RES 226.8m

Comment: Hmm, I suspect the MariaDB variable showing wrong data. Thr OS reported memory usage is OK.

Comment: Ok, hopefully next MariaDB version will fix the issue...
Thanks a lot for your help and your time.

Comment: I updated to MariaDB 10.1.10 but it didn't fix the issue. Instead it created similar issue on all my servers I updated with the last version of MariaDB.